# ¿Cóno cambiar un label de color con condición en python?

Tags: python, tkinter

Hola tengo una duda de como podría hacer que una etiqueta pudiera cambiar su color y texto en base a unos `checkbutton` sencillos.

```
chk1=Checkbutton(ventana,text=' + RECEPCION DE INCIDENTE',onvalue=1,offvalue=0,bg='#6F6F6E') chk1.place(x='535',y='300')

chk2=Checkbutton(ventana,text=' + CANALIZACION DEL INCIDNTE',onvalue=1,offvalue=0,bg='#6F6F6E') chk2.place(x='535',y='320')

chk3=Checkbutton(ventana,text=' + LLEGADA DE UNIDAD(ES)',onvalue=1,offvalue=0,bg='#6F6F6E') chk3.place(x='535',y='340')

chk4=Checkbutton(ventana,text=' + NOVEDAD DE LA UNIDAD',onvalue=1,offvalue=0,bg='#6F6F6E') chk4.place(x='535',y='360')

chk5=Checkbutton(ventana,text=' + FINALIZACION DE INCIDENTE',onvalue=1,offvalue=0,bg='#6F6F6E') chk5.place(x='535',y='380')

Cemaforo_activo =Label(text='#00000',font=('Arial Black',12),bg='#BDBDBD').place(x=5,y=5)
```

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías poner el color del label con una variable y así dependiendo de la elección que haga con los checkbutton se cambiaría el color

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).